# Numbers arent formatting with Decimal style

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

So i have an app which should format the value string in a SecondviewController to display on the firstViewController tab.

When a user enters numbers, its suppose to format it using a comma every 3 digits. But somehow i cant seem to get how to display it onto the firstViewController. Here is my code:

In secondViewController.m

```
    -(IBAction) button:(id)sender{

       NSString *string1 = self.addDigitField.text;

       /* format the entered digits */
       NSNumberFormatter *format =     [NSNumberFormatter new];
       [format setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
       NSNumber *n = [format numberFromString: addDigitField];

       /* display the string1 value to the firstViewController Label*/

       self.string1 = [self. addDigitField text]
       FirstViewcontroller *first = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
       first.fvcString = self.string1;
       }
```

now firstViewController.m

```
       /* display the value into firstViewController label *
     -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
      If (self.svcString != nil)
          self.displayValue.text = self.svcString;
        }
```

So my problem is, where in this code do i put the the message method to format the
Number ? The code i am trying to add is as follow :

```
      [format stringFromNumber: n];
```

I typically use this way when doing it all on a single view app:

```
         self.label.text = [format stringFromNumber: n];
```

And it formats it. But in my case of formatting the string to a firstViewcontroller
From the secondViewcontroller is where i am lost, any suggestion where i am going 
Wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

In your second view controller, replace

```
first.svcString = self.string1;
```

with

```
first.svcString = [format stringFromNumber:n];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line below :-

```
  self.string1 = [self. addDigitField text];
```

In this your are setting the text value which is the previous value. You need to set the NSNumber value which you have converted using number formatter. Try like this

```
NSNumber *n = [format numberFromString: 
addDigitField];
self.string1 = [format stringFromNumber:n];
FirstViewcontroller *first =   
self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
   first.fvcString = self.string1;
```

Now in your first view controller just replace the below line

```
   self.displayValue.text = self.fvcString;
```